# How to pass the output of one method to another in RSpec?

Tags: rspec

I have a class called `db_conn.rb` in which I have 2-methods 
1. One method is to check if db connection is established or not which is called `is_conn?` 
2. Another one is to close db connection i.e., `close_conn`.

Now I want to write `rspec` for `close_conn`. My logic is to run `close_conn` and then call `is_conn?` to check the boolean value which should be `false`.

Below is my spec file. I need more guidance in achieving this.

```
describe DdModule::DbConnn do
   before(:context) { 
       puts "Testing DB connection..."
       @obj = DbModule::DbConn.new("hostname", "instance", "port", "user", "pass")
    }


it "connect_db constructor takes five parameters and returns true if connection establishes" do
    expect(@obj.is_conn?).to eq true
end

it "connect_db close_connection should close the connection and is_connection should return false" do
    @obj.close_conn
    expect(@db_obj.is_conn?).to eq false
end
```

I am seeing the following output:

```
rspec
Testing DB connection...
Oracle Connection user@jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521/instance initialized..
.FFF

Failures:

1) DbModule::DbConn close_connection should close the connection and is_conn should return false
 Failure/Error: expect(@obj.is_conn?).to eq false

   expected: false
        got: true

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/conn_db_spec.rb:21:in `(root)'
Finished in 0.2 seconds (files took 0.27 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failures
```

Comment: Are you intentionally using `before :context` rather than `before :example`?

Comment: What is @db_obj?  Didn't you mean @obj?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an instance method that you expect to change with another instance method, you need to write your expectation like this (i made a test class locally to ensure it works).

```
expect {@obj.close_conn}.to change(@obj, :is_conn?).from(true).to(false)
```

If it were me, I would write the full spec like this

```
describe DdModule::DbConnn do
  let!(:db_conn) do 
    DbModule::DbConn.new("hostname", "instance", "port", "user", "pass")
  end

  describe '#close_conn' do
    it 'closes the db connection' do    
      expect {db_conn.close_conn}.to change(db_conn, :is_conn?).from(true).to(false)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @MilesStanfied, thank you very much for the details. I tried to include the `expect` line suggested by you. Now I am seeing the following error message: `Failure/Error: expect(@db_obj.close_connection).to change(db_obj, :is_connection?).from(true).to(false)`
       `expected #is_connection? to have changed from true to false, but was not given a block.`

Comment: because your mixing the two things i said. i put `expect {db_conn.close_conn}.to` not `expect(@db_obj.close_connection).to`